# how to detect a whitespace on string in php program

Tags: php, string, whitespace, detect

I want to do treatments on two strings, and I must to know if there are spaces to stop my treatment and move on to the rest of characters
I tested that but it doesn't rule the problem :

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < $lenght; $i++) {

                    if($text[$i] <> '' && $mask[$i] <> ''){

                        $nbrcrypted = $stringtonumber[$text[$i]] + $stringtonumber[$mask[$i]];
                        $resultat .= $numbertostring[$nbrcrypted];
                    }else{

                        $indice = false;
                    }                    
                }
```

how can I achieve that, thank you in advance

Comment: Define "whitespace." Do you mean spaces only? Horizontal tabs? Carriage returns? Line feeds?

Answer (score 2):

`if($text[$i] <> '' && $mask[$i] <> ''){` is useless, use `if($text[$i] !== ' ' && $mask[$i] !== ' '){` for spaces

Answer (score 1):

I don't get what you're actually trying to do but if you want to test your string for whitespaces:

```
if ( strpos( $yourString, ' ' ) !== false )
    null; // string has whitespace(s)
```